# Mongoid Validation Error "Email Can't be blank" when testing with rspec & Capybara, but fields are not blank

Tags: ruby, mongodb, rspec, capybara, mongoid

I am running into an error when writing an rSpec Capybara test to mock a user signing up for the website.

It should be noted that, unfortunately, I am writing a test for a codebase that is entirely new to me, so a lot of the code for the main program is unknown to me. If asked for something I will try and dig up the relevant code, but I'm not certain what else to include at the moment. However I can say it has been successfully running in production for a while, and I can manually test it successfully - so I think the error is probably in my test, or perhaps some configuration used just while testing.

**rspec test**

```
RSpec.describe 'New User Sign Up', type: :feature do
  scenario 'valid signup inputs' do
      visit("/users/sign_up")
      fill_in 'user_name', with: 'TEST'
      fill_in 'user_email', with: 'TEST@test.com'
      fill_in 'user_username_with_caps', with: "TEST"
      fill_in 'user_password', with: 'TESTpw123'
      puts find_field('user_email').value
      puts expect(find_field('user_email').value).to eq 'TEST@test.com'
      puts expect(page).to have_selector("input[value='TEST@test.com']")
      puts page.should have_field('user_email', with: 'TEST@test.com')
      click_on 'Create an account'
  end
end
```

The output is:

```
bgc@jadzia:~/Documents/Work/BadgeList/code/badgelist/backend/spec$ bundle exec rspec sign_up_spec.rb
TEST@test.com
true
true
true
F
Failures:
  1) New User Sign Up valid signup inputs
     Failure/Error: click_on 'Create an account'
     Mongoid::Errors::Validations:
       message:
         Validation of User failed.
       summary:
         The following errors were found: Email can't be blank
       resolution:
         Try persisting the document with valid data or remove the validations.
```

Note the puts statements and the corresponding output before the error message.

As far as I can tell, the fields *ARE* getting filled in properly. However, somehow this does not get recognized when it attempts to complete the sign up. The error is coming from Mongoid, so somehow mongo reacts differently to an testing auto-entered field vs. a manually entered one.

It should also be noted that, if I disable [database_cleaner-mongoid](https://github.com/DatabaseCleaner/database_cleaner-mongoid), and run the same test twice... I get a -DIFFERENT- outcome. The test technically passes, but there is a warning prompt on the page that says "This email is taken".

So, somehow the value in the email field is...

- Being entered/read properly when directly querying the field value on the page
- Not recognized when it immediately afterwards tries to use that value to Create an account, instead the field is seen as blank.
- But ALSO the field is successfully saved into the DB for a new account with this information, so running the same test again creates a conflict with the entry from the previous test if the DB is not cleaned first.

Comment: Put a breakpoint in your application and see what data is being assigned to the fields.

Comment: It is all being assigned properly, I have confirmed this by checking the logs that mongod is getting the expected info. After consulting with my team this issue has been put on hold as it probably is an issue outside the scope of rspec testing.

Answer (score 0):

All `click_on` does is click on the button. It doesn't wait for the server to do anything, or anything on the page to change, etc. So ending the test with `click_on` isn't actually testing for any behavior, and the DB is going to get reset while the action triggered by `click_on` is still occurring, which is unlikely to be what you want. You need to add an expectation after the `click_on` testing for what you expect to see in the page like

```
...
click_on 'Create an account'
expect(page).to have_text('User created!!!)
```

Also note that the expectations you are calling `puts` on aren't actually defined to return anything specific, so the fact you're seeing `true` really is just luck.  They're defined to not raise an error when successful, and raise an error when not.

Comment: Thanks. Originally I did just that - I followed click_on with `expect(page).to have_text(Welcome)`. This failed, as it breaks before even reaching the expect, and the next/confirmation page never loads. I removed it while I focus on getting the test to run past `click_on` and to be sure it loads a new page before I worried about what content is on that page. Now it never gets to that page because the test breaks on "Create Account"/

Thanks for the tip on the puts! Although note that they don't raise errors, so doesn't that mean the text is as expected? The first puts makes that clear.

Comment: @BrianC Yes, my note was just to make sure you weren’t depending on seeing true output. Next steps would be to add back your final expect so test cleanup isn’t happening while the app is still processing the create action, then check your test.log to see what’s actually being submitted  in the request,. If the submission is correct then check your user controller create action for things like restrictions on email addresses (test.com not an allowed sub domain, etc)

Comment: As I figured, adding it back changes nothing. It never reaches the expect statement. I checked the log, and its a bit hard to follow but "TEST@test.com" appears multiple times in there, There is no indication of any errors or failures in the log. I will check where the create account action is done next, although i'm not sure where it is... and I would expect the bug is not there... but perhaps it bring up an edge case that causes tests to fail